# how to configure Extensible in extjs Application

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am new in Ext.js and i am working on a Projekt so i have to use Extjs extensible (calendar pro: Ext\extensible-1.5.2)..

I download it but i don't really know how to configure and use it in my extjs application.

i put it in the library but it not seems to work and i don't have a single idea how to achieve it. I don't really know how to bind it with my Project. 
Any help ? Thanks.

the documentation don't really talk how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all include the **extensible-all.js** and **extensible-all.css** to your project.

Then follow the [api](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/) or copy [examples](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/).

for more instructions look at [gitHub](https://github.com/bmoeskau/Extensible).